# PHP will not write to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to write a login function for a website but for some odd reason the MySQLi `query` command seems to not be working.  It passes with no error but when I look at the table its empty.

Below is the code in question.

```
$hash = password_hash(($_POST['password']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$hash = $sql_link->real_escape_string($hash);
$_POST['username'] = $sql_link->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

// Escape the input data
$cmd = ('INSERT INTO web_creds(email, pass, joined) ' .
                    'VALUES ' .
                    '("'.$_POST['username'].'", ' .
                        '"'.($hash).'", ' .
                        'NOW()' .
                        ')');

if (!$sql_link->query($cmd) === TRUE) {
    $err[]="input failed " . $sql_link->error;;
}

else if($sql_link->affected_rows==1)
{
    $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']="Passed";
}
else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
```

I run it and I see the query in the logs.

`57 Query     INSERT INTO web_creds(email, pass, joined) VALUES ("email@domain.com", "hashed-password", NOW())`

but when I run `select * from web_creds` I just get `EMPTY`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running the query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Have a space between `web_creds` and `(email, pass, joined)`. Final query `INSERT INTO web_creds (email, pass, joined) VALUES ("email@domain.com", "hashed-password", NOW())`

Comment: @Ashish Adding the space did not work.

Comment: What eror you are getting in PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: What is the Storage engine of the Table which you have created ?

Comment: @JoshuaPelino Your query looks very primitive and there are no syntaxic errors there. Did you try it in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez but that does not answer why it is not being written.  I think that is more important ;)

Comment: An aside, but this is burning my eyes :P. `!$sql_link->query($cmd) === TRUE`

Comment: try this out var_dump($sql_link->query($cmd)) to know what is the result of your query. and one more thing if you can get the date now in phpside rather than the mysql function. try to do so. and value it on your query as string

Comment: @Anandthakkar it is the default MyISAM.

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez the var_dump returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

(Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection)

The SQL statement it is generating is not valid - you've put double quotes around the strings (should be single quotes or use binding).

(Comment: I, and I expect most others, consider it sloppy not use explicit database names in queries)

Would it be so hard to add:

```
 print "<div>$cmd</div>";
```

into your code?

(Comment: why all the brackets?)

Try this:

```
$cmd = "INSERT INTO web_creds(email, pass, joined)
    VALUES
    ( '$_POST[username]'
    , '$hash)'
    , NOW()
    )";
```

Comment: I tired the new `$cmd` and I am still getting the same result.  How ever phpmyadmin connects no problem and can manipulate the data easily.  This is starting to get frustrating.